# Почему border-radius не применяется к параграфу у которого задан border-image

Tags: css

```
.about__more-sub{
    border: 3px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(136.96deg, #EB177E 0%, #893EF9 103.66%);
    border-image-slice:1;
    border-radius: 17px;
    border-image-repeat:;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте HTML, где применяется и не работает стиль ".about__more-sub"

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds/#corner-clipping «Although border images are not affected by border-radius,…»

Comment: @AlexeyTen, почему не ответом?

Comment: @Grundy я хотел найти что-то более подробное чем эта одна фраза, но не смог, а потом отвлёкся…

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я не помню чтобы именно с border-image в общем проблема была, но сталкивался именно когда туда градиент впихиваешь

Answer (score 0):

я нашёл решение.

```
.about__more-sub{
border: double 3px transparent;
border-radius: 17px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#Ffffff,#ffffff), radial-gradient(circle at top left, #EB177E,#893EF9);
background-origin: border-box;
background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}
```